# mongo-express service in minikube doesnt seem to work with its username and password

Tags: mongodb, environment-variables, minikube

So ive set env variable for mongodb password and username using a secret in minikube

```
PS C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\to do 29th\civ ser jobs apps\minikube\youtube-tutorial-series-master\demo-kubernetes-components> kubectl exec -it mongo-express-859f75dd4f-xtthk -- env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=mongo-express-859f75dd4f-xtthk
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=tgmjack
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb-service
............ skip many more lines ..........
```

#######  I get the service runing

```
PS C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\to do 29th\civ ser jobs apps\minikube\youtube-tutorial-series-master\demo-kubernetes-components> minikube service mongo-express-service
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |         NAME          | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | mongo-express-service |        8081 | http://192.168.49.2:30000 |
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
* Starting tunnel for service mongo-express-service.
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |         NAME          | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | mongo-express-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:14817 |
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|------------------------|
* Opening service default/mongo-express-service in default browser...
! Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

##########

I get an alert popup that says

```
sign in to access this site

Authorization required by http://127.0.0.1:14817

username [------------]

password [------------]
```

the username and password in the environment variable doesnt work.

1. shouldnt it?
2. what should i try?
3. what other info would be helpful?

######################

I'm at 1:45 in this tutorial, Ive followed every step.

tutorial = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X48VuDVv0do&t=1099s

it didnt work so then i just downloaded her actual files and tried again incase i made a typo i couldnt see . it still didnt work.

files = https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/youtube-tutorial-series/-/tree/master/demo-kubernetes-components?ref_type=heads

Answer (score 0):

kubectl logs 
kubectl logs

Run this an the output logs will give as

credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js

Username:admin
Password:pass